# 16.04 Restrict the ability to change the desktop wallpaper and greeter wallpaper

Tags: 16.04, unity, desktop-background, unity-greeter

I have seen threads with this question so many times but have yet to find a real solution. How can someone restrict permissions, capabilities, etc. of changing a wallpaper both as background and greeter. A few school computers are set up with Ubuntu and it would be really great if it didn't have a really bad picture... Now, I have a very simple script to reset it on login but the greeter still shows the changed wallpaper, which is an issue. Is there any tool, commands, or possibility to remove any capability of changing the background/greeter? (even as root)

Base details: 16.04, Unity DE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say "even as root", the answer is no. All of the methods of restriction built in to Ubuntu rely on the user you're trying to restrict not being able to become root. If you want to set any serious restrictions on your users, you need to block their root access.

Comment: so, only users can be restricted, i get that... but, is there at least the chance of restricting the user like in gnome? all the articles about this talk of gnome but not unity